# How to sort the choices in a Wicket dropdown according to the current user locale?

Tags: localization, wicket

I have the following issue:

- a drop down with a list of elements
- each of these elements has a fixed key, which is used by the IChoiceRenderer implementation to look up the localized version of the key (it's a standard, utility renderer implemented in a different package)
- the list of localized keys is in a properties file, linked to the panel which instantiates the dropdown.

Is there an elegant/reusable solution to have the dropdown display its elements sorted alphabetically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this extension of DropDownChoice using Java's [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) (basically locale sensitive sorting - take national characters and national sorting rules into account)

Code tested with Wicket 6 and Java 5+:

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IChoiceRenderer;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;

import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

/**
 * DropDownChoice which sort its choices (or in HTML's terminology select's options) according it's localized value
 * and using current locale based Collator so it's sorted how it should be in particular language (ie. including national characters, 
 * using right order).
 * 
 * @author Michal Bernhard michal@bernhard.cz 2013
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class OrderedDropDownChoice<T> extends DropDownChoice<T> {

    public OrderedDropDownChoice(String id, IModel<? extends List<? extends T>> choices, IChoiceRenderer<? super T> renderer) {
        super(id, choices, renderer);
    }

    public OrderedDropDownChoice(String id, IModel<? extends List<? extends T>> choices) {
        super(id, choices);
    }

    public OrderedDropDownChoice(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public OrderedDropDownChoice(
            String id,
            IModel<T> model,
            IModel<? extends List<? extends T>> choices,
                    IChoiceRenderer<? super T> renderer) {

        super(id, model, choices, renderer);
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends T> getChoices() {
        List<? extends T> unsortedChoices = super.getChoices();
        List<? extends T> sortedChoices = Ordering.from(displayValueAlphabeticComparator()).sortedCopy(unsortedChoices);

        return sortedChoices;
    }

    private Collator localeBasedTertiaryCollator() {
        Locale currentLocale = Session.get().getLocale();
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(currentLocale);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.TERTIARY);

        return collator;
    }

    private Comparator<T> displayValueAlphabeticComparator() {

        final IChoiceRenderer<? super T> renderer = getChoiceRenderer();

        return new Comparator<T>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
                Object o1DisplayValue = renderer.getDisplayValue(o1);
                Object o2DisplayValue = renderer.getDisplayValue(o2);

                return localeBasedTertiaryCollator().compare(o1DisplayValue, o2DisplayValue);
            }
        };

    }


}
```

Copied from https://gist.github.com/michalbcz/7236242

Comment: I made this the accepted solution, for the record, so maybe you could put your code completely in your solution.

Comment: That being said, I think it'd be better as a Behavior, that way you could still inherit from another DropDownChoice subclass.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I think using the render is probably the best approach. To make it reusable and efficient, I isolated this in a Behavior.

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.Behavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IChoiceRenderer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.sort;

/**
 * This {@link Behavior} can only be used on {@link AbstractChoice} subclasses. It will sort the choices
 * according to their "natural display order" (i.e. the natural order of the display values of the choices).
 * This assumes that the display value implements {@link Comparable}. If this is not the case, you should
 * provide a comparator for the display value. An instance of this class <em>cannot be shared</em> between components.
 * Because the rendering can be costly, the sort-computation is done only once, by default,
 * unless you set to <code>false</code> the <code>sortOnlyOnce</code> argument in the constructor.
 *
 * @author donckels (created on 2012-06-07)
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public class OrderedChoiceBehavior extends Behavior {

    // ----- instance fields -----

    private Comparator displayValueComparator;
    private boolean sortOnlyOnce = true;
    private boolean sorted;

    // ----- constructors -----

    public OrderedChoiceBehavior() {
    }

    public OrderedChoiceBehavior(boolean sortOnlyOnce) {
        this.sortOnlyOnce = sortOnlyOnce;
    }

    public OrderedChoiceBehavior(boolean sortOnlyOnce, Comparator displayValueComparator) {
        this.sortOnlyOnce = sortOnlyOnce;
        this.displayValueComparator = displayValueComparator;
    }

    // ----- public methods -----

    @Override
    public void beforeRender(Component component) {
        if (this.sorted && this.sortOnlyOnce) { return;}
        AbstractChoice owner = (AbstractChoice) component;
        IChoiceRenderer choiceRenderer = owner.getChoiceRenderer();
        List choices = owner.getChoices();

        // Temporary data structure: store the actual rendered value with its initial index
        Object[][] displayValuesWithIndex = new Object[choices.size()][2];
        for (int i = 0, valuesSize = choices.size(); i < valuesSize; i++) {
            Object value = choices.get(i);
            displayValuesWithIndex[i][0] = choiceRenderer.getDisplayValue(value);
            displayValuesWithIndex[i][1] = i;
        }

        sort(displayValuesWithIndex, new DisplayValueWithIndexComparator());
        List valuesCopy = new ArrayList(choices);
        for (int i = 0, length = displayValuesWithIndex.length; i < length; i++) {
            Object[] displayValueWithIndex = displayValuesWithIndex[i];
            int originalIndex = (Integer) displayValueWithIndex[1];
            choices.set(i, valuesCopy.get(originalIndex));
        }
        this.sorted = true;
    }

    public Comparator getDisplayValueComparator() {
        return this.displayValueComparator;
    }

    // ----- inner classes -----

    private class DisplayValueWithIndexComparator implements Comparator<Object[]> {

        // ----- Comparator -----

        public int compare(Object[] left, Object[] right) {
            Object leftDisplayValue = left[0];
            Object rightDisplayValue = right[0];
            if (null == leftDisplayValue) { return -1;}
            if (null == rightDisplayValue) { return 1;}

            if (null == getDisplayValueComparator()) {
                return ((Comparable) leftDisplayValue).compareTo(rightDisplayValue);
            } else {
                return getDisplayValueComparator().compare(leftDisplayValue, rightDisplayValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that in some situations it push wrong selection to the model. If using ChoiceRenderer so that it renders option's id attribute from index of particular choice (see ChoiceRenderer#getIdValue) and you are using some ajax form submitting behaviour then it won't call beforeRender so getChoices are the old unsorted one... I created this solution: https://gist.github.com/michalbcz/7236242

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Wicket-based solution you can try to sort the list with something like that:

```
public class ChoiceRendererComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final IChoiceRenderer<T> renderer;

    public ChoiceRendererComparator(IChoiceRenderer<T> renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return ((Comparable<Object>) renderer.getDisplayValue(o1)).compareTo(renderer.getDisplayValue(o2));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<Entity> list = ...
    IChoiceRenderer<Entity> renderer = ...
    Collections.sort(list, new ChoiceRendererComparator<Entity>(renderer));
    DropDownChoice<Entity> dropdown = new DropDownChoice<Entity>("dropdown", list, renderer);
```

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, but in order to use the renderer properly, you have to have your hierarchy done completely (otherwise the localizer component of wicket cannot search properly for translations and will issue warning messages).

Comment: @FDO you should overwrite onInitialize() instead of doing work in the constructor. This is recommended since Wicket 1.5. The hierarchy is initialized then.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we use at my company is Javascript based, we set a special css class on the dropdowns we want to be sorted, and a little jQuery trick does the sort.

Comment: As a last resort, that's what I was thinking of doing.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, I moved part of the localisation data from my XMLs to the database, implemented a matching Resolver and was able to use the localized Strings for sorting. 
The table design and hibernate configuration was kind of tricky and is described here: [Hibernate @ElementCollection - Better solution needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103300/682559).

The ResourceLoader is along these lines:

```
public class DataBaseStringResourceLoader extends ComponentStringResourceLoader {

    private static final transient Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(DataBaseStringResourceLoader.class);

    @Inject
    private ISomeDAO someDao;
    @Inject
    private IOtherDao otherDao;
    @Inject
    private IThisDAO thisDao;
    @Inject
    private IThatDAO thatDao;

    @Override
    public String loadStringResource(Class<?> clazz, String key, Locale locale,
            String style, String variation) {
        String resource = loadFromDB(key, new Locale(locale.getLanguage()));
        if (resource == null) {
            resource = super.loadStringResource(clazz, key, locale, style, variation);
        }
        return resource;
    }

    private String loadFromDB(String key, Locale locale) {
        String resource = null;
        if (locale.getLanguage() != Locale.GERMAN.getLanguage()
                && locale.getLanguage() != Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()) {
            locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        }
        if (key.startsWith("some") || key.startsWith("other")
                || key.startsWith("this") || key.startsWith("that")) {
            Integer id = Integer.valueOf(key.substring(key.indexOf(".") + 1));
            ILocalizedObject master;
            if (key.startsWith("some")) {
                master = someDao.findById(id);
            } else if (key.startsWith("other")) {
                master = otherDao.findById(id);
            } else if (key.startsWith("this") ){
                master = thisDao.findById(id);
            } else {
                master = thatDao.findById(id);
            }
            if (master != null && master.getNames().get(locale) != null) {
                resource = master.getNames().get(locale).getName();
            } else if (master == null) {
                logger.debug("For key " + key + " there is no master.");
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
[...]
    }
```